# $E=mc^2$ explanation needed

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

My question is pretty standard and easy,I wonder all my life how Einstein get energy equation [$E=mc^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence).

Also I some videos about that equation on YouTube and some of the peoples said there that the equation $E=mc^2$ isn't full.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43813/2451

Comment: $E=c^2 m$ only applies to an object you observe to be at rest. When the object has momentum $p$, the complete energy-momentum equation $E^2 - (c p)^2 = (c^2 m)^2$ needs to be applied. For an accessible discussion, see: http://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/whats_wrong_emc2