# What is the derivation of $E=mc^2$?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, mass-energy

1. How did Einstein derive his most famous equation:
   $$E=mc^2$$
2. Is the above equation a special case of 
   $$E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$$
3. Its derivation?
4. What is the difference between them?

Comment: do you mean Einstein's original derivation or any derivation will do?

Comment: the original [1905 paper of Einstein on the electrodynamics of moving bodies](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/) already contains a form of this relation

Comment: this is a [second paper of Einstein on the relation between inertia and energy](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/www/) and contains a further form of the relation

Comment: @Nikos M it would be helpful if you can furnish me with Einstein's original derivation, as long as it does not involve too much calculus(I am fine with basic calculus); although I will be indebted to you for any logically consistent proof

Comment: Einstein's papers of 1905,1906 on special relativity, do not involve contrived mathematics apart geometry and physical reasoning

Comment: a summary of the derivations in modern form in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation) and [wikipedia2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43813/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143652/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic, this question is older than one of the possible duplicates (maybe that could be a duplicate, it has answers of course)

Comment: @Nikos M.: Note that age is not always decisive when deciding which is a duplicate of which.