# $E=mc^2$ what is unique about the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

What *unique* property of light, makes it the conversion factor between energy and mass? It has to be more than a coincidence that the speed of light, just happens to be the correct number number to convert mass to energy

Comment: possible duplicate of [What was Albert Einstein's proof for $E=mc^2$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43813/)

Comment: The coincidence is just that light quantum, photon, has zero mass, thus it travels with highest possible speed.