# Can "mass" be eliminated as a concept by always thinking of it as energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, dimensional-analysis, mass-energy

In the Newtonian sense, "mass" is representative of a body's general resistance to motion. Einstein derived $E = mc^2$ but it was in the context of the amount of mass lost after a body emits some amount of light with energy $E$. In that context, $m$ is more like a $\Delta m$. Another interpretation of $E = mc^2$ is, for a body of mass $m$, $E$ is the total amount of *electromagnetic* energy you could get out of it if all of its mass were converted to light radiation.

Both interpretations of $E = mc^2$ seem to refer to specific thought experiments/hypotheticals, and it seems that $E$ always refers to the energy carried by light in any of these interpretations, so we are constrained to conceive of it in that way.

My question though is: is it possible, since we do have a relation between $E$ and $m$, to simply eliminate the concept of inertia entirely? For example, why not just substitute $\frac{E}{c^2}$ as $m$ into ${\bf F} = m{\bf a}$ and work instead with energies, forces, and motions? In this setting, we have to conceive of energy as "the capacity for a body to perform work on its surroundings," rather than a constant of motion that arises from a time-translation symmetry. "Mass" becomes a potency for a body's ability to both create light and perform work.

Wouldn't this eliminate a concept ("mass," whatever it is) and streamline the theories? But maybe the classical interpretations are just more attractive over thinking in terms of potency all the time. Not to mention the practical aspect of having extremely large numbers to work with once the speed of light is baked into all the equations.

Comment: Why are you putting the word "mass" in quotes, but not the word "energy." Are you applying some special meaning to the word "mass" beyond the conventional meaning?

Comment: Einstein famous formula $E_{0}=m c^2$ states only that mass $m$ of a body is proportional to its rest energy $E_{0}$ and not that energy is equivalent to mass, see  L. B. Okun  [The Einstein formula: E0=mc^2](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0437v1) .

Comment: You may eliminate the concept of mass in favor of the energy (however you should be consistent, and shouldn't mix relativistic formulae with the Newtonian relation between force and acceleration). Once you have done such a substitution, you have the concept of energy in place of that o mass. Not a particular imrovement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer, by "mass," I mean ["rest mass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) (sometimes called the "invariant mass").

Mass isn't *equivalent* to energy -- if you take the word "mass" and simply replace it with "energy" everywhere you find it written in a physics books, you will end up with some incorrect or at best very misleading statements. Mass is a *form* of energy. In particular,  mass is the lowest energy that a particle can have -- it is the energy of a particle at rest (so long as the mass is larger than zero). We can distinguish particles by whether their mass is zero or non-zero. Furthermore, the mass of a particle sets the energy scale at which that particle becomes relevant; one reason (not the only reason) it took so long to discover the Higgs in the history of particle physics, is that its mass is quite large (compared to, say, the electron and proton), so it took a while to build generators that could produce collisions with energies large enough to produce a Higgs.

Therefore, I do not think it would be useful to retire the concept of mass. Mass is a type of energy that tells us several useful things about a particle's intrinsic properties. The total energy of a particle also includes information about its state of motion and its interaction with other particles, which are not intrinsic to the particle.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking if you can absorb the concept of energy to also include mass. Sure, they're just words.

The distinctions between "mass" and other forms of energy would still exist. It wouldn't make mass more similar to other forms of energy.

In QFT, we already make heavy use of the mass-energy tensor, and use "natural units" that make mass and energy the same units. That helps streamline the theory, calling mass "energy" wouldn't help streamline it any more.

In the classical regime, using $\frac{E}{c^2}$ wouldn't provide any advantage over using rest mass. It's still got unique units $\frac{J \cdot s^2}{m^2}$

Answer (score 2):

The speed of light is a constant, so we can work in a system of units where $c = 1$. In that case:
$$E^2 = m^2 + p^2 => m = \sqrt{E^2 - p^2}$$
Different observers would disagree on the energy of the object, but would agree on its mass. Mass is an invariant scalar of an object, while energy depends on the particular frame.

Comment: *Rest* mass is invariant, *relativistic* mass isn't.  *Mass* is ambiguous in relativistic physics, since it's used for both concepts.

Comment: @JohnDoty as far as I know, relativistic mass is not used anymore. But anyway, I use it here in the meaning of rest mass.

Comment: So, you never see $E=mc^2$ anymore? Open your eyes.

Comment: For something at rest in my frame.

Comment: Or for something that's moving in your frame, with you applying force to it.

Comment: Well, in this case there is a momentum, and $E^2 = m^2 + p^2$ (for c = 1)

Comment: That's one way to do it. But see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron#Relativistic_considerations. Relativistic mass is more physical, less abstract, for problems like this.

Comment: Claudio, how is ${\bf p}$ defined? To make sense of your answer I assume it is not defined simply as the arbitrary combination ${\bf p} = \gamma m_0 v$, as then you would need to factor out an $m_0$ for your relationship between an invariant/intrinsic quantity and relativistic, variant, observer-dependent ones: $m = \sqrt{E^2 - p^2}$. Is momentum defined through the concept of force, i.e., "momentum is that quantity which increments when an impulse is supplied to a body." ??

Comment: It seems that the most satisfactory definition is in defining it from the action, which in turn is defined using the Lagrangian, which in turn is defined using energies...

Comment: @HelpMe I would say that it is defined as $\gamma m\mathbf v$ for a massive body indeed, where $m$ is the invariant mass. And the momentum of an electromagnetic pulse is the $\Delta p$ of a body that absorbs it. By the way, in this last context the relation between $E$ and $m$ is found, as shown for example in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/491568/195949